# 沒verb vs 沒有verb

Tags: translation, grammar

I encountered this in one of my language learning apps. What is the difference between

昨天這個男孩沒**有**喝牛奶 (by google translate: The boy did not drink milk yesterday)

and

昨天這個男孩沒喝牛奶 (by google translate: The boy did not drink milk yesterday)

Do these mean the same thing? Or is there some slight difference between 沒有喝牛奶  and just 沒喝牛奶？

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are exactly the same meaning giving your context, when they before a verb.

Also notice that, "没" itself have the meaning "not have". That means "没" = "没有" even when they before a noun.

- 我没钱。= 我没有钱。= I have no money.

There is a little difference between the Taiwan dialect of mandarin and the mainland one, maybe informal.  That is, when I say, "I have done it." In Taiwan version, we can say, 我有做过，in mainland, we say, 我做过。 But the negative form is the same, 我没（有）做过。
I am not sure "我有做过" is formal in Taiwan, but in mainland, it is definitely be thought as informal and "too Taiwan".

Answer (score 2):

昨天這個男孩沒有喝牛奶 sounds a bit formal.

昨天這個男孩沒喝牛奶 is casual.

No difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it is exactly the same, there is no difference. I am Chinese, believe me. When you use these two sentences in your life, you can use either one to see your mood.